# Emacs keep opening lots of buffers (Clojure)

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I'm a beginner in Clojure and for some reasons I decided that Emacs would be a good choice, because of its usage among the clojurists.

But something that's really anoying me is that Emacs (for working with Clojure projects) opens a bunch of buffers. i.e, when I click "Read a directory to operate in its files" and select the lein's project root, I need to select myproject.core.clj and Emacs keep all the super dirs openned in other buffers. When compiling with cider and working with many clj files, it's painful to keep on alternating through all those buffers.

**How can I limitate the numbers of buffers that Emacs leave openned?**

(I know C-x k)

(Sorry for any English mistakes)

Comment: this is a fundamental part of emacs' design, and for people who choose to continue using emacs, the typical choice is to find a better method of selecting buffers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a lot of trouble with this same problem when I first started using Emacs. The solution is to use something other than `C-x b` or `C-x C-b` to switch between buffers. In particular:

- I use [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)'s `C-c p f` to switch to arbitrary files in my project. It works very nicely because it takes your `.gitignore` into account. This can be [annoying](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20118/8900) in some cases, but for the most part it works very well.
- I use [`project-explorer`](https://github.com/sabof/project-explorer) to browse through a tree view of all the files in my project. The ignore features of `project-explorer` aren't quite as nice as those of Projectile, but you can toggle them using `M-o` when you need to, which is a feature Projectile doesn't have. `project-explorer-open` doesn't have a default binding, so I bind it to `C-x p`.
- I use Ido and [`ido-ubiquitous`](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous) to make all selection commands (including `C-c p f`) much easier to use.
- If you lose your REPL buffer in [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), you can get it back instantly using `C-c C-z`.
- If you already have multiple windows in front of you, `windmove` provides an extremely fast way to switch between them.

You'll generally end up with a lot of open buffers anyway, but since you now have an easy way to switch between them, that's no longer a problem. You can find a full example of this sort of setup in [my personal Emacs config](https://github.com/elogent/env/blob/master/emacs.el).

Comment: Hey there! Thank you for the answer. Do you know if there's a more intuitive version of Emacs, like others text editors but with all the Emacs "cool things"?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "intuitive". Obviously Emacs may seem unintuitive at first, but after you use it a while you'll develop an intuition for it. Or did you have some specific features in mind?

Comment: "Normal" key-bindings, repl, code highlighting, autocomplete, etc. Not much. Just a good text editor with suport for clojure and repl.

Comment: As for keybindings: in this case, you can either get "normal" *or* efficient. If the former is more important to you, I suggest you use something besides Emacs. I'm not sure what you mean by "repl, code highlighting, autocomplete, etc."; [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) has arguably the best Clojure REPL available, with decent code highlighting. You can get fairly good autocomplete with a combination of CIDER and [Company](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode).

Comment: Hmmmm... I understand. I'm used to brackets, sublime, visual studio, etc. Emacs is _really_ different. I'll give a try, but I'm considering to use Cursive (but is paid for commercial use).

Comment: That's fine. Emacs is the most popular option for Clojure development, but if you find something else that suits you better, you should use that instead. One thing's for sure: if you want you use Emacs, you're going to be changing not only Emacs (through Emacs Lisp), but also yourself. That's just how Emacs is.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use `C-x C-f` to open files, and don't bother with opening buffers for directories.